# creating an object from two views

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to create a concert.  This concert have many informations and a place where it will be.

In the first view. I have a form to create a new concert (time of starting, band playing, time of finish, price). In the second view, I have a table of places stored in the DB. The user has to choose a place from the existing places.

I will then store the concert object with information + concert_id in the DB. My problem is that I don't know how to proceed with that.

EDIT:
here's what i want to do

```
concert form -> click submit -> redirect to locations dataTable 
and choose one location-> get the location_id and add it to my instance of       concert -> click submit 
-> save in the database
```

So, I created new_concert.html.erb with a submit button, once clicked, the create action is executed
the create action is defined as follow

```
def create
@concert =current_user.concerts.build(concerts_params)
respond_to do |format|
  format.html { redirect_to choose_location_path(@concert), 
  notice: 'Vous participez a ce concert.' }
end
end
```

this must redirect me to choose_concert_path.html.erb that contains the locations dataTable as follow. this causes me a problem because the concert_id is nil.Indeed the concert is not saved in the database yet.

```
 <div class="datatable">

                            <table class="table table-bordered table-hover"data-provides="rowlink">
                                <thead>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th align="center">Nom</th>
                                        <th align="center">Type</th>
                                        <th align="center">Pays</th>
                                        <th align="center">Ville </th>
                                        <th align="center">Quartier</th>
                                        <th align="center">Détail</th>
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody>
                                <% Location.all.each do |location| %>


                                    <tr >
                                                <td align="center">

                                        <%= location.name %></a></td>
                                        <% if location.type==true %>
                                        <td align="center">
                                        hall
                                        </td>
                                        <% else %>
                                        <td align="center">
                                        stadium
                                        </td>
                                        <%end%>

                                        <td align="center"><%= location.country %></td>
                                        <td align="center"><%= location.city %></td>
                                        <td align="center"><%= location.adress%></td>

                    <td align="center"><%=link_to "<i class='icon-link'></i> Choisir".html_safe, choose_location_path(location) ,method: :put, class: "btn btn-sm btn-success"  %></td>
                                    </tr>


<% end %>
                                </tbody>

                            </table>
                        </div>
```

when the location is choosen i have to click a button that saves my concert_params+location_id in database. 
To conclude, my two problems are:

```
 1- passing the @concert from one view to another
 2- get the id of selected location_id and add it to the other informations
```

I hope this time i explained more clearely.

Comment: Welcome to SO.  I'd suggest reading http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, which will help you write good questions (and--in turn--get better answers).

Comment: I would also recommend checking out the Rails docs themselves at http://rubyonrails.org/documentation/

Answer (score 0):

This is an incredibly broad question. I know you requested two views but I think that radio buttons are the best solution to this problem so my example will be all in one view. You can apply this to use multiple views. 
Here is a form with radio buttons:

```
<%= form_for @concert do |form| %>
<!--- insert the concert fields up here --->
<p>Concert Location</p>
<%= form.radio_button :career_goal, "location_one" %>
<%= form.label :concert_location, "Location One", value: "location_one" %></br>

<!--- add the rest of your options the same way as the above two lines--->
```

The concert_location is just a string and it will take the value you give it in the string parameter of the radio button. You can put images and the like in the radio button as well if you want. If you have any further questions let me know.

Edit* I decided I didn't adequately answer because you did specifically request two views, so here you go.

concerts_controller.rb:

```
class ConcertsController < ApplicationController
   def new
      @concert = Concert.new
   end

   def create
      @concert = Concert.new(concert_params)
      if @concert.save
         redirect_to concert_location_path(@concert.id)
      else
         #whatever you want to do upon failure
      end
   end

   def locations_list
      @concert = Concert.find_by_id(params[:id])
      @locations = Locations.all
   end

   def add_location
      @concert = Concert.find_by_id(params[:id])
      if @concert.update_attributes(concert_location_params)
         #wherever you want to take them upon success
      else
         #whatever you want to do on failure
      end
   end

   private
   def concert_params
      params.require(:concert).permit(:first_param,...)
      #don't add concert_location here
   end

   def concert_location_params
      params.require(:concert).permit(:concert_location)
   end
end
```

new.html.erb:

```
<%= form_for @concert do |form| %>
   <!--- concert fields except for location --->
   <%= form.submit %>
<% end %>
```

concert_list.html.erb:

```
<%= form_for @concert, :url => add_location_path(@concert.id), :method => "patch" do |form| %>
   <p>Concert Location</p>
   <%= @locations.each |location| do %>
      <%= form.radio_button :concert_location, location.id %>
      <%= form.label :concert_location, Location.name, value: "location.id" %></br>
   <% end %>
   <%= form.submit %>
<% end %>
```

Add this to your routes.rb:

```
resources :concerts

get '/concerts/location_list/:id' => 'concerts#locations_list', as: :concert_location
patch '/concerts/add_location/:id' => 'concerts#add_location', as: :add_location
```